# how to download https file from url

Tags: java

i am trying to download from these url

"https://www.treasury.gov/ofac/downloads/sdn.xml" 
but it is saying that

```
"javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target"
```

I have tried below two,but it's not working
1. `System.setProperty("com.sun.security.enableAIAcaIssuers","true");`
2. updated my java version from 1.7 to 1.8.0_121

```
download("https://www.treasury.gov/ofac/downloads/sdn.xml","D:\\AML_Files\\Download_Check\\sdnList.xml");

public static void download(String url, String fileName) throws Exception { 
//System.setProperty("com.sun.security.enableAIAcaIssuers","true");
try (InputStream in = URI.create(url).toURL().openStream()) {
            Files.copy(in, Paths.get(fileName));
        }
    }
```

i want to download xml file in my system and after that insert that xml file data  to database table

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? Are you getting an error? The wrong result?

Comment: I am able to download file with your code.  "download(url,"sdnList.xml");".  So I guess this is not related to JRE. My Java version is "1.8.0_144"

Answer (score 0):

you need to add valid certificate in JRE.